How to implement joining muiltiple curves is Catia VBA?
I am trying to write a macro in CATIA VBA that takes multiple curves as input, joins them and then gives me a single curve. The input curves will be non connex. There will be at leas two curves. The code that I have will work if there are two curves but fails when there are more than two.
Here is my code:
Attribute VB_Name = "Join_Explicit_No_Connect"
Option Explicit

    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    '   Macro: Join_Explicit_No_Connect.bas
    '   Version: 1.0
    '   Code: CATIA VBA
    '   Release:   V5R32
    '   Purpose: Macro to join multiple un connected curves and isolates them
    '   Author: ************
    '   Date: 13.09.24
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    '
    '   Change:
    '
    '
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    
Sub CATMain()
    CATIA.StatusBar = "Join_Explicit_No_Connect.bas, Version 1.0"    'Update Status Bar text
    
    'On Error Resume Next
    
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    'Declarations
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim PartDocumentCurrent As Document                             'Current Open Document
    Dim partCurrent As Part                                         'Current Open part
    Dim sel As CATBaseDispatch                                      'User Selection
    
    Dim InputObjectType(0) As Variant                               'iFilter for user input
    Dim Status As String                                            'Status of User selectin

    Dim Index As Integer                                            'Index for loops
    Dim cCount As Integer                                           'Curves Count

    Dim joinCurves As HybridShapeAssemble                           'New Join
    Dim RefCurves() As Reference                                    'Curve references
    
    Dim Wzk3D As CATBaseDispatch                                    'hybridshapefactory anchor
    Dim geoSet As HybridBody                                        'Geomeetric set
    Dim searchName As String                                        'Name of item to search
    
    Dim hybridShapesCount As Integer                                'Number of items in set
    
    Dim Error As Integer
    
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    'Open Current Document
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    Set PartDocumentCurrent = CATIA.ActiveDocument                  'Current Open Document Anchor

    If (Right(PartDocumentCurrent.Name, (Len(PartDocumentCurrent.Name) - InStrRev(PartDocumentCurrent.Name, "."))) = "CATProduct") Then
        Error = MsgBox("This Script only works with .CATPart Files" & vbNewLine & "Please Open a .CATPart to use this script or Open part in new window", vbCritical)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If (Right(PartDocumentCurrent.Name, (Len(PartDocumentCurrent.Name) - InStrRev(PartDocumentCurrent.Name, "."))) = "CATProcess") Then
        Error = MsgBox("This Script only works with .CATPart Files" & vbNewLine & "Please Open a .CATPart to use this script or Open part in new window", vbCritical)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set partCurrent = PartDocumentCurrent.Part                      'Current Open Part Anchor

    Set sel = PartDocumentCurrent.Selection                         'Set up user selection
    sel.Clear                                                       'Clear Selection
    
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    'Get User selection
    '
    ' "MonoDimInfinite"  = Topological 1-D entity which may be infinite
    '
    '
    'CATMultiSelTriggWhenUserValidatesSelection
    '   Multi-selection is supported (through a dedicated "Tools Palette" toolbar).
    '   The selection (through a trap for example) is triggered when the user validates the selection.
    '   The CTRL and SHIFT keys are supported.
    '
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    InputObjectType(0) = "MonoDimInfinite"                          'Set input type to curves
    'Get Input from User, get selections untill user acepts
    Status = sel.SelectElement3(InputObjectType, "Select curves to join", False, CATMultiSelTriggWhenUserValidatesSelection, False)
    
    If (Status = "Cancel") Then                                     'If User cancels or presses Esc, Exit Macro
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If sel.Count2 < 2 Then                                          'At least two things need to be selected
        Error = MsgBox("You need to select at least two curves", vbCritical)
        sel.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ReDim RefCurves(sel.Count2)                                     'Dynamic allocation acording to user input
    cCount = sel.Count2                                             'The amount of selected items
    For Index = 1 To sel.Count2                                     'Cycle through all inputs
        Set RefCurves(Index) = sel.Item2(Index).Reference           'Save selections to array
    Next
    sel.Clear                                                       'Clear Selection
    
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    'Create new join
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Wzk3D = partCurrent.HybridShapeFactory                      'Anchor hybridshapefactory for use
    
    Set joinCurves = Wzk3D.AddNewJoin(RefCurves(1), RefCurves(2))   'Create new hybridshape assemble feature
    
    If cCount > 2 Then
        For Index = 3 To cCount                                     'Cycle through rest of curves
            joinCurves.AddElement (RefCurves(Index))                'Add curves to join
        Next
    End If
    
    joinCurves.SetAngularTolerance (0.5)                            'Set angle tol
    joinCurves.SetAngularToleranceMode (False)                      'Turn off angle tol mode
    joinCurves.SetConnex (False)                                    'Turn off check connex
    joinCurves.SetDeviation (0.001)                                 'Set merge distance
    joinCurves.SetFederationPropagation (0)                         'Set to no
    joinCurves.SetHealingMode (False)                               'No Heal
    joinCurves.SetSimplify (False)                                  'No simplify
    joinCurves.SetSuppressMode (True)                               'True is only option
    joinCurves.SetTangencyContinuity (False)                        'No tangent continuity
    
    searchName = partCurrent.InWorkObject.Name                      'Get name of in work object
    
    If StrComp(searchName, partCurrent.Bodies.Item(1).Name) = 0 Then    'If body is inwork object create new geo set
        Set geoSet = partCurrent.HybridBodies.Add()                         'Add New set
    Else
        sel.Search "(NAME =" & searchName & "),all"                     'Search for in work object
    
        Set geoSet = sel.Item2(1).Value                                 'Anchor geo set
        sel.Clear                                                       'Clear Selection
    End If
    
    geoSet.AppendHybridShape joinCurves                             'Add join to set
    
    hybridShapesCount = geoSet.HybridShapes.Count                   'Number of items in set
    geoSet.HybridShapes.Item(hybridShapesCount).Name = "TEMP_JOIN"  'Rename Join
    
    partCurrent.Update                                              'Update Part
    
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    'Create Datum
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    sel.Search "(NAME =TEMP_JOIN),all"                              'Select temp_join
    sel.Copy                                                        'Copy
    sel.Clear                                                       'Clear Selection
    
    sel.Search "(NAME =" & geoSet.Name & "),all"                    'Select geoSet
    sel.PasteSpecial ("CATPrtResultWithOutLink")                    'Paste from clipboard as result without links
    sel.Clear                                                       'Clear selection
    
    hybridShapesCount = geoSet.HybridShapes.Count                   'Number of items in set
    sel.Search "(NAME =Join_Explicit.*),all"                         'Select all joins from this macro
    geoSet.HybridShapes.Item(hybridShapesCount).Name = "Join_Explicit." & sel.Count + 1 'Rename curve
    sel.Clear                                                       'Clear Selection
    
    sel.Search "(NAME =TEMP_JOIN),all"                              'Select temp_join
    sel.Delete                                                      'Delete Selection
    
End Sub

I get my failure here when there are more than two curves as input:
    If cCount > 2 Then
        For Index = 3 To cCount                                     'Cycle through rest of curves
            joinCurves.AddElement (RefCurves(Index))                'Add curves to join
        Next
    End If

I'm not sure if I am using the hybridShapeAssemble correctly. I assumed it would work like the normal gui join command where you can add as many elements as you want, but maybe it works different in the code?
V5Automation.chm describes AddElement as:
Sub AddElement(Reference iElement) 
    Adds an element to the hybrid shape assemble feature object.  Parameters: 
    iElement 
        The element to add to the hybrid shape assemble feature object. 
        Sub-element(s) supported (see Boundary object): Face, TriDimFeatEdge and BiDimFeatEdge.  Examples:  The following example adds the iElement feature object to the HybridShapeAssemble object. 
     HybridShapeAssemble.AddElement iElement

Any help or advice of how to join multiple curves?
I tried joining multiple curves, but the code only works for two curves.

What error/failure do you get? Your code works for me (other release, run as catscript)

Object doesn't support this property or method. Ive tried it on V5R32 and V5R30 .

In VBA you need to use either the CALL keyword when calling methods with parenthesis and passing objects as arguments, or just skip the parenthesis.
If cCount > 2 Then
        For Index = 3 To cCount                                     
'Cycle through rest of curves
            Call joinCurves.AddElement (RefCurves(Index))                
'Add curves to join
        Next
End If

Or
joinCurves.AddElement RefCurves(Index)

